# I have a specific requirement in Java to read a CSV and find the longest parent child relationship

Tags: java

I have a CSV file:
The contents of the file looks like as shown in the attached image:

[image]

We have two columns in the file:

```
Parent | Child
```

Need to parse the file to find the longest parent child relationship.
In the above stated example the output should be as:

```
Darrel->Aisha->John->Sam
```

Comment: You just have to read the file from inputstream, then use split to store the data in a Map<K, V>, then looping it and find out what you need.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have a _specific_ problem or question about the code you've written so far? Stackoverflow is not a forum or a code-writing service, it is a Q & A site.

Comment: @PSo A Map might not work as people can have multiple children

Comment: @ThijsSteel I guess you can put arrayList in to value there

Comment: @PSo Yeah, just though of that, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is with recursion. The longest parent-child relation for a given child is the longest parent-child relation of each of its parents extended by itself. (i hope that makes sense)

I've provided some code to illustrate the idea (note that this code is not well written, if you plan on using this please handle exceptions correctly)

Main class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Person> parents = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Person> children = new HashSet<>();

        //Build tree
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"))){
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                String[] parentChild = line.split("\\|");
                Person parent, child;
                //find or create parent
                if(personMap.containsKey(parentChild[0]))
                    parent = personMap.get(parentChild[0]);
                else{
                    parent = new Person(parentChild[0]);
                    personMap.put(parentChild[0], parent);
                }

                //find or create child
                if(personMap.containsKey(parentChild[1]))
                    child = personMap.get(parentChild[1]);
                else{
                    child = new Person(parentChild[1]);
                    personMap.put(parentChild[1], child);
                }

                //add parent to child
                child.addParent(parent);

                parents.add(parent);
                children.add(child);

                line = reader.readLine();
            }


        }

        Set<Person> pureChildren = new HashSet<>(children);
        pureChildren.removeAll(parents);

        //Find longest path
        List<Person> longest = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Person person:pureChildren){
            List<Person> path = person.getLongestPath();
            if(path.size() > longest.size()){
                longest = path;
            }
        }

        //print path
        for(Person p:longest){
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

And the Person class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private Set<Person> parents = new HashSet<>();

    private List<Person> longestPath = null;

    /**
     * Initialize a new person
     */
    public Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Return the name of this person
     * @return
     */
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Return a copy of the parent set
     */
    public Set<Person> getParents(){
        Set<Person> copy = new HashSet<>();
        copy.addAll(parents);
        return copy;
    }

    /**
     * Add a parent to this child.
     */
    public void addParent(Person parent){
        parents.add(parent);
    }

    /**
     * Return the longest child-parent path, starting from and including this person
     */
    public List<Person> getLongestPath(){
        if(longestPath == null){

            longestPath = new ArrayList<>();
            longestPath.add(this);
            for(Person parent:parents){
                List<Person> path = parent.getLongestPath();
                if(path.size() >= longestPath.size()){
                    path.add(0,this);
                    longestPath = path;
                }
            }
        }

        return new ArrayList<>(longestPath);
    }

}
```

CSV file used: (i used | as separator because that seemed to be the case in your example, edit the splitting of the line in the main class if you use a different separator)

```
Sam|John
Mark|Tom
John|Aisha
Aisha|Darrel
Jimmy|Salman
Anne|Salman
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

1) Find some good implementation of tree in Java that have all convenient methods for adding childs/ parents etc.

2) Parse CSV file and populate tree.

3) Your task becomes finding of longest path in that tree.
[See this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-path-undirected-tree/)

Comment: Finding longest path in tree is for an undirected tree. Here we only want the directed parent-child relation

Comment: As I said, in step 2 populate tree according to parent - child relationships that exists in CSV file. Than find longest "path" in that tree.

Comment: Yeah, but say that A and B are children of C. I think the link you provided would return A-C-B.

Comment: Oh you are talking about link, I just provided it as a general idea about algorithms for traversing through tree.